# Regarding convolution of Fejér kernel with a Lipschitz function

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, lipschitz-functions, fejer-kernel

Let $\mathbb{T}$ be the unit circle in the complex plane. The Lipschitz class of functions on $\mathbb{T}$ is defined
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a91Fd.jpg). And the Fejér kernel is defined [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RqVs.jpg). If $f\in Lip_{\alpha}(\mathbb{T}),\, 0<\alpha <1$, then how to show that 
$$\|K_n*f-f\|\leq C_{\alpha}\frac{\|f\|_{Lip_{\alpha}(\mathbb{T})}}{n^{\alpha}}$$ when $C_{\alpha}$ is an absolute constant depending on $\alpha$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $$\begin{align}|K_n*f(x)-f(x)|&=\left|\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi K_n(t)(f(x-t)-f(x)\,dt\right|
\\&\le\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi K_n(t)|f(x-t)-f(x)|\,dt.\end{align}$$

So now all you need is a suitable upper bound for $\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi K_n(t)|t|^\alpha=\frac1\pi\int_0^\pi K_n(t) t^\alpha$. **Don't** try to work out that integral exactly. Instead note that $\sin(t/2)\ge ct$ for $0\le t\le \pi$, so
$$\begin{align}\int_0^\pi K_n(t)t^\alpha
&\le \frac cn\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin^2(nt/2)}{t^2}t^\alpha
\\&=\frac c{n^\alpha}\int_0^{n\pi}\frac{\sin^2(t/2)}{t^2}t^\alpha
\\&\le \frac c{n^\alpha}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(t/2)}{t^2}t^\alpha;\end{align}$$note that the last integral is finite since $\alpha<1$.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell how how $\frac{c}{n}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{{sin}^2(nt/2)}{t^2}t^\alpha$=$\frac{c}{n^\alpha}\int_{0}^{n\pi}\frac{{sin}^2(t/2)}{t^2}t^\alpha$?

Comment: That's a change of variable; $s=nt$...

Comment: Can you tell how you accomadated the extra $n^2$?

Comment: This is just first-semester calculus! Take the integral on the left, and _work out_ what you get from the substitution $s=nt$.

Comment: @Anthony $|\sin(t)|\le  1$. Also $\sin(t)|\le|t|$

Comment: @David C. Ullrich thank you. It was the behaviour of the function around zero that I was unsure of, but I finally worked it out.